# Heatmap using amcharts5 grid and react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, matrix, amcharts, amcharts5

**Objective**
I'm trying to generate programatically a matrix of colored squares like the one on the picture.

**Details**
Which is theoretically divided in 4 quadrants, meaning the second-right one is the more vivid one whilst the other three are less vivid because they have less meaning.

**Problem**
I'm having problems adding the series correctly to do so, they seem to overlap each other and produce an unwanted result.

Here's a link to a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-breeze-3ywu2q?file=/src/App.js

[image: expected result]